# Заливка тега use в SVG в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

Добрый день.
Я работаю над интеракивной SVG-картой для небольшого проекта, и столкнулся с проблемой кроссбраузерности.

После некоторого времени разбора проблемы, я нашёл её источник и написал аналог с такойже проблемой. Вот его код:

```
<svg version = "1.1"
baseProfile="full"
xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="400"
height="400">
<style><![CDATA[
    #elems g use {
        fill: white;
    }
    #elems g use.minus {
        fill: gray;
    }
]]></style>
<defs>
    <g id="rects">
        <rect id="r1" x="25" y="25" width="350" height="150" />
        <rect id="r2" x="25" y="200" width="350" height="175" />
        <rect id="r3" x="50" y="225" width="300" height="125" />
    </g>

    <g id="elems">
        <g id="e1">
            <use xlink:href="#r1" />
        </g>
        <g id="e2">
            <use xlink:href="#r2" />
            <use xlink:href="#r3" class="minus" />
        </g>
    </g>

    <g id="main">
        <use xlink:href="#e1" />
        <use xlink:href="#e2" />
    </g>    
</defs>

<rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="gray" />
<use xlink:href="#main" />
```

Это же пример в [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kozhilya/ks3ftq50/1/). Скриншот результата в приложенном изоражении.

SVG-определения разбиты на части:

- в `g#rects` хранятся простейшие формы активных областей (в оригинале используется `<path>`, но проблема не зависит от этого.
- в `g#elems` при помощи `<use>` сохраняется информация об областях, которые будут использоваться. В основном, это простые формы (с одним `<use>`), но встречаются и сложные. Так, в примере показан случай, когда нужно "вычесть" одну область из другой.
- в `g#main` просто копируются элементы из `g#elems`. В оригинальном проекте вместо этого используется маска, которая наложится на оригинальное изображение и подсветит активную область.

В итоге в Chrome и IE получается правильная маска, но в Firefox заливки почему-то не происходит. Красить всю область вместо отдельных частей - не вариант, так как иногда нужно вычитать области, а переносить части в элементы (то есть описывать прямоугольники или пути прямо в `g#e1`) не желательно, так как если так сделать, то становится трудно вносить правки, к тому же некоторые элементы используются несколько раз (например, как сам элемент, и в качестве "вычитаемого" для другого).

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

[image: Результат примера из JSFiddle в GC 46 и MF 40]